# ComplexTypes and dynamicwrapper

Tags: c#, ilgenerator

[DynamicWrapper](http://dynamicwrapper.codeplex.com/) lets associate interface to object in this way

```
IDoSomething actor = objectWithoutInterface.As<IDoSomething>();
```

How can I extend this library so that I can write something like

```
actor.Get(MyTypeCopy myComplexObject);
```

in order to call

```
objectWithoutInterface.Get(MyType myComplexType);
```

where MyTypeCopy is a copy of MyType in another namespace?

One soulution would be to add

```
Get(dynamic myComplexObject);
```

to the interface, and apply the cast (Serialization/Deserialization) before invoking the method.

Is there a way to add a DynamicMethod to apply the cast inside the DynamicWrapper library?

Answer (score 0):

just add

`ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, convertType);`

after pushing each parameter